# What is the best practice in attaching R scripts with examples to an R package?

Tags: r, package

I wonder what is the best practice in attaching R scripts with examples to an R package. I mean R script with examples such as:

- go somewhere beyond simple function running example (e.g. come with plot with visualization), have 10-30 lines of code and thus seem for me too long to put them as **"Example" in the package documentation**
- are extracts from larger paper which will go as **a vignette to the package** itself, so it seems for me maybe not the best idea to include it as just another vignette, shorter than this main one

I am not sure if there are any other "elegant" ways of including such examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use

- the `demo/` directory, or
- an `inst/examples/` directory

The former leads to use by `demo()` and has some extra requirements spelled out in Writing R Extensions, the latter is simpler.

Lastly you of course just write a vignette document ...